# C# development for Chromecast

Tags: c#, google-cast

I would like to create a sender application for ChromeCast, I don't know if this is possible or not.Is there any way of doing this? I've seen some samples for iOS, Android, and Chrome webbrowser. Also I've seen some special ports using an external tool for porting the SDK to C#, but I would like to have native support.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible using [Sharpcaster](https://github.com/Tapanila/SharpCaster).

Also look at [GoogleCast](https://github.com/kakone/GoogleCast).